# Update new data in face recognition model

Tags: python, opencv, model, face-recognition

Below code always overwrite the data even if the label is changed

```
    recognizer = cv2.face.LBPHFaceRecognizer_create()
    recognizer.train(images, np.array(labels))
    recognizer.save('trainedData.yml')
```

When I am taking some images of person 1 then I am saving it like all images of that person and label as 0
 Now Again when I am saving images of person 2 and taking label 2 ( I believe label will be different) 
 When I check the yml it only has data for label 2.

How to update with new data

Thanks

Comment: Could you explain the problem more? Which data is overwritten?

Comment: I have updated the post